# adding a new component to Joomla 2.5.8 giving error

Tags: joomla2.5

I have tried to add a new component to Joomla 2.5.8 and getting the following error:

> Error loading component: com_mycomp, 1
>
> Error loading component:com_mycomp, 1
>
> Error loading component: com_mycomp, 1

The following steps I have done :

1. created a folder com_mycomp under components. and created a file `mycomp.php` under com_mycomp.
2. created  a folder com_mycomp under `administrator/components/` and  a file `admin.mycomp.php` under com_mycomp.

Accessed the url :

```
http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_mycomp
```

> Error loading component: com_mycomp, 1

Any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: i think this link will be helpful http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_01

Comment: consider sharing your component files, maybe in a https://gist.github.com/ so that we can spot your error.

Comment: there is no content in componets files, it is blank. I was just trying to load the component.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few problems going on here:

1. when doing a "manual" installation you should use the Joomla! `Extensions Manager` to `Discover` your manually installed extension (this works for components, modules, plugins and templates).
2. The minimum files (and directories) you need are the entry point file (`mycomp.php`) and an manifest file (`mycomp.xml`) to provide the basic menu elements etc, as [discussed in this article](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_01).

Answer (score 0):

IT seams you add this component only in filesystem. you must add this component in database to, in table #__extensions type is component. just take some component row in this table and paste it and change only names with your component name